# Meus componentes não estão sendo renderizados pelas tags do reactjs, o que posso fazer para resolver isso?

Tags: react, route

Minhas tags do reactjs (BrowserRouter e Route) não estão renderizando os meus componentes Home e Sobre. A tela não apresenta erro nenhum, apenas não renderiza nada no navegador, fica tudo branco. Já testei a renderização isolada dos componentes, exemplo: `<Home />`, dessa forma eles são renderizados, descartando assim a possibilidade do erro estar nos componentes. Já verifiquei a instalação do react-router-dom, já reconstruí o projeto react via linha de comando umas duas vezes também. Estou ficando sem opções.
Seguem meus códigos:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import Home from "./Home";
import Sobre from "./Sobre";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>         
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/sobre" component={Sobre} />
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = () =>{
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Página Home</h1>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

**Sobre**

```
import React from 'react';

const Sobre = () =>{
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Sobre</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sobre;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve adicionar o "Routes" por volta dos elementos "Route", trocar component por element, e usar os componentes dentro do element assim `<Home/>`, que ficaria assim:

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "./Home";
import Sobre from "./Sobre";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
   return(
      <BrowserRouter>
         <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
            <Route path="/sobre" element={<Sobre/>} />
         </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
   );
}
export default App;
```

Caso tenha outra dúvida tente consultar a documentação: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente agora. Obrigado.